# scripts/basic/fixdep: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, driver, rpmbuild

When installing some driver by ./install.sh (ex: https://www.mellanox.com/products/adapter-software/firmware-tools ), I see this log:

```
scripts/basic/fixdep: No such file or directory
```

but I do have this file.

```
ll /lib/modules/4.15.20/build/scripts/basic/fixdep
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 22240 May  5 03:02 /lib/modules/4.15.20/build/scripts/basic/fixdep
```

before the driver installation (./install.sh), I had done:

```
gunzip < /proc/config.gz > .config
make oldconfig
make prepare
make scripts
```

ref:
https://serverfault.com/questions/568395/what-is-creating-the-generated-autoconf-h

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I fixed it like this:

go your linux header files :

probably for ubuntu/debian:

```
cd /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-97-generic
```

custom linux distro / yocto:

```
cd /usr/src/kernel
```

then execute **"make scripts"**

you will see like this screen:

```
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/bin2c
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/flattree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/fstree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/data.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/livetree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/treesource.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/srcpos.o
.
.
```

now check the fixdep file out under **../scripts/basic/** file path.